# Get Speakers out of AudioDevices

Tags: c#, wpf, screen-capture, audio-device

I'm trying to do a ScreenCapture using Microsoft Expression Encoder.
I want to get the Speakers out of AudioDevices (NOT the Microphone).
My Problem is, that every Device has another name for it's speakers.

I came up with the solution to check, if the device's name contains "Speaker", but i think this won't work on every clients device.

```
private EncoderDevice GetAudioDevice()
{
    EncoderDevice audioDevice = null;
    Collection<EncoderDevice> audioDevices = 
        EncoderDevices.FindDevices(EncoderDeviceType.Audio);

    try
    {
        foreach (var item in audioDevices)
        {
            if (item.Name.ToUpper().Contains("SPEAKER"))
            {
                audioDevice = item;
            }
            else
            {
                audioDevice = audioDevices.First();
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Keine AudioDevices gefunden!");
    }

    return audioDevice;
}
```

Anybody knows how to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`EncoderDevice` has a `Category` enum property. Test with

```
if (item.Category == EncoderDeviceCategory.Playback)
{
    ...
}
```

A microphone would have a `Category` of `EncoderDeviceCategory.Capture`.

See:

- [EncoderDevice Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/design-tools/expression-studio-4/ff726603(v%3Dexpression.40))
- [EncoderDevice.Category Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/design-tools/expression-studio-4/gg603746%28v%3Dexpression.40%29)
- [EncoderDeviceCategory Enumeration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/design-tools/expression-studio-4/gg591137(v%3Dexpression.40))

Comment: Can't find "Category".... i added using Microsoft.Expression.Encoder.Devices;
Why?

Comment: I don't have this DLL myself, so it's hard to tell. Do you have an older version?

Comment: I downloaded the latest version and it worked :) Thx